# Oracle SQL Sum dollars into quarters

Tags: sql, oracle, date, sum

I would like the output to be:

```
VENDOR_ID    FY13Q1     FY13Q2      FY13Q3    FY13Q4 ...  
ABC123       5000       NULL        NULL      10000  
DEF321       10000      8000        15000     2000
```

From the table:

```
VENDOR_ID VARCHAR  
GROSS_AMT NUMERIC  
INVOICE_DT DATE
```

This query works BUT I need to find a more efficient way (if possible):

```
SELECT T1.VENDOR_ID, FY13Q1, FY13Q3, FY13Q4, FY14Q1, FY14Q2, FY14Q3, FY14Q4  
FROM   
(   
SELECT VENDOR_ID, SUM(GROSS_AMT) AS FY13Q1  
FROM PS_VOUCHER   
WHERE INVOICE_DT BETWEEN '01-JUL-12' AND '30-Sep-12'   
GROUP BY VENDOR_ID   
) T1   
FULL JOIN    
(      
SELECT VENDOR_ID, SUM(GROSS_AMT) AS FY13Q2   
FROM PS_VOUCHER   
WHERE INVOICE_DT BETWEEN '1-Oct-12' AND '31-Dec-12'   
GROUP BY VENDOR_ID    
) T2   
ON T1.VENDOR_ID LIKE T2.VENDOR_ID
```

...

FY13Q3 through FY14Q4 looks the same as above except the dates are changed to match the quarter.  Any ideas on how to simplify this using a CASE statement or GROUP BY?

Comment: Hint:  `SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'Q') from DUAL;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original query is inefficient, because the query makes oracle read the table multiple times. Almost all of this kind of problem can be solved by reading the table once.

You can use `pivot` to simply the query, if you are using oracle 11g or above.

```
select * from (
  select vendor_id, to_char(invoice_dt, 'yyyy-q') yyq, sum(gross_amt) amt
  from ps_voucher
  group by vendor_id,  to_char(invoice_dt, 'yyyy-q')
)
pivot (
  sum(amt)
  for yyq in ('2013-1', '2013-2', '2013-3', '2013-4', '2014-1', '2014-2', '2014-3', '2014-4')
)
order by vendor_id;
```

If you are using 10g or below, you should use `decode` function or `case` clause. Perhaps you want to read this: http://oracletuts.net/sql/three-ways-to-transpose-rows-into-columns-in-oracle-sql/